# AJAX refuses to send variable to PHP (All other answers checked)

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, variables, post

This is a much answered question. But after checking all other answers, I still have not been able to resolve my issue.

This JS function used to work and suddenly stopped working

JS

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js" data-pagespeed-orig- type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>
$('document').ready(function(){
$('select[name="Developer"],[name="City"],[name="PossesionDate"],[name="PropertyType"],[name="Cost"]').change(function()
      {
        filtproj();
      });
   });  

    function filtproj(){
    var dev=$('select[name="Developer"]').val();
    var city=$('select[name="City"]').val();
    var podate=$('select[name="PossesionDate"]').val();
    var ptype=$('select[name="PropertyType"]').val();
    var cost=$('select[name="Cost"]').val();
        alert(dev);
        $.ajax({
            type:'POST',
            url:'filtprojs.php',
            data:{dev:dev,city:city,podate:podate,ptype:ptype,cost:cost},
            success:function(filtres){
                console.log(dev);
                alert(filtres);
                $('.newp').html(filtres);
            },
            error: function() {
                  alert("error");
              }
        });
    }
</script>
```

PHP file filtprojs.php returns empty POST Values. Alerting variables before Ajax displays correct variable values. It displays correct variable values even when checked in console.log from inside the 'success' function.

For the life of me, I am not able understand why it is not posting to the PHP file.

I have replaced all the code in the filtprojs.php with

> var_dump($_POST)

This outputs 0

// Adding below line because the is question was 'Closed' saying there is no specific question here !

The specific question here is - Why are the JS Variables not being passed to the file filtprojs.php ?

UPDATE

It is sending variables as GET type. But not POST type!

Comment: what you mean with "it used to work"? what is the content of filtprojs.php file?

Comment: perhaps you ought to add the code from `filtprojs.php` too?

Comment: @GiacomoM have edited the question and have mentioned that I have tried to output $_POST with var_dump in filtprojs.php to see whether variable is not received there

Comment: @ProfessorAbronsius Have updated the question with information about filtprojs.php

Answer (score 1):

The JavaScript code seems to be OK. The following snippet is a PoC and shows that it basically works. I substituted your "filterprojs.php" with a publicly available test site.

```js
const sels={dev:"Developer",city:"City",podate:"PossesionDate",ptype:"PropertyType",cost:"Cost"};
$('document').ready(function(){

// quickly create some select elements ...
$("form").html('<select name="'+Object.entries(sels).map(([k,v])=>v+'">'
      +[...Array(5)].map((o,i)=>'<option>'+v+i+'</option>').join('')).join('</select>\n<select name="')+'</select>')

$('select[name="Developer"],[name="City"],[name="PossesionDate"],[name="PropertyType"],[name="Cost"]').change(filtproj);
});  

function filtproj(){
  $.ajax({
    type:'POST',
     url:'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users',
    data:Object.entries(sels).reduce((a,[k,v])=>(a[k]=$('select[name='+v+']').val(),a),{}),
 success:function(res){ console.log("response from POST request:",res); },
   error: function()  { console.log("POST error"); }
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form></form>
```

Comment: Mine still doesn't work

Comment: I fully believe you but suspect that it is caused by either you not being able to reach the target address or your `filtproj.php` having a problem. The JavaScript part is definitely OK.

Comment: filtprojs.php has only var_dump($_POST) now. I removed everything else to check the POST variables. And it shows 0. And I dont know why i am not able to reach the target address as i have many other processes i do similarly

Comment: Can you do a test by diverting to a different address (both: the local and maybe also the external typicode.com address)?